# Sudo java -jar vs java -jar

Tags: java, jar, raspberry-pi, sudo, pi4j

I have a server running on Java using the library Pi4j to control the RaspberryPi's GPIOs and a file on which I write the current GPIOs' statuses. When I run the code from IntelliJ IDE everything works just fine.
But when I create the .jar file and run it like

```
sudo java -jar server.jar
```

It works fine updating the file, but the GPIOs do not change their status.
When I do

```
java -jar server.jar
```

The GPIOs correctly change their status but I get the error *java.io.FileNotFoundException: relStat.txt (Permission denied)*

[image]
My file permission are all set to *anyone*, so anyone should be able to read, modify and run it.
Why does this happen?

Comment: GPIO needs low level hardware access which the pi user doesn't have access to, hence the need to prefix with `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a permission issue, 
The file owner is the "pi" user. 
Which user you are running under?

Comment: I'm running under pi.

Comment: Did you add the "pi" user to the sudoer file (https://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer-using-the-command-line )? anyway this is required, do that and post the results